# Reliability of backed up data

Tags: backup

Is there any information on how reliable the different back up processes as such are? Put simply if I do a back up 1 million datapoints, how many data points would normally be corrupted or lost?

Thanks

Comment: Bad question, because it's very dependent on the medium you back up to and a lot of other factors.  Acceptable "casualties" as @computercarguy says should be 0 - otherwise it's not really a backup.

Comment: "Accepted causalities" should be 0, but expected casualties is always above 0; a fact the OP is trying to figure out while seemingly not knowing how the deep the rabbit hole really is.

Comment: Many people are routinely backing up multi terabyte drives, fully expecting that every byte will be exact. That usually happens. A single error would be a failed backup. If that happened to me once I would question the reliability of the backup drive. If it happened twice I would likely replace the drive. If that level of reliability was not routine the computer industry could not have reached the level it has today.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of a backup is that there shouldn't be any loss.  That depends on how many years and read/writes your media is good for, but it should still be 0% loss.

In fact, backing up your data should ensure against loss.